# Es posible utilizar docker en windows sin poseer VT-x/AMD-v?

Tags: docker, virtualización, windows7

Buen día comunidad de StackOverflow!

He logrado instalar docker en una maquina que es x64 y posee Windows 7 Ultimate, sin embargo, como docker es un programa que tiene soporte oficial para x64 bits y además utiliza virtual box estuve leyendo que es necesario para el correcto funcionamiento que la maquina soporte la virtualización a nivel de hardware y de hecho al correr docker éste me arroja un mensaje justo diciendo que la maquina no tiene soporte para sistemas x64 bits. El problema es que la maquina no posee esta capacidad (he leído sus especificaciones técnicas, revisé también en la Bios y por si quedaban dudas confirmé que no posee Hyper-V en la características de Windows).

Lo que me lleva a preguntar si existe alguna otra herramienta, "workaround" o alternativa para poder correr docker en Windows 7 sin utilizar virtualización por hardware de por medio.

**Observación:** Se que cambiar a Linux es una solución porque no requiere de la tecnología de virtualización a nivel de hardware, sin embargo, no es una opción ya que el host debe ser Windows por los requerimientos que se me han planteado.

**Actualización:** A petición del usuario @Alfabravo he tomado captura de pantalla con el error que muestra docker por el problema de virtualización por hardware.

Imagen docker quick toolbox:

[image: Docker quick toolbox]

Imagen de docker "corriendo" en virtual box:

[image: Docker virutal box driver]

Comment: Podrías por favor, poner la traza de error de Docker cuando intentas usar la máquina?

Comment: Actualizada mi pregunta con la traza de error de Docker @Alfabravo. Disculpa la tardanza

Comment: Mi portatil tiene el procesador i7 4510U que teóricamente es compatible con VT-X y aun activandolo en bios, tengo el mismo mensaje que tu al iniciar el docker quickstart. Con windows 10 pro se ve que se activa de forma nativa.

Comment: El problema es que muchas veces al activar VT-X por primera vez parece que la bios presenta un fallo, entonces debes reiniciar, desactivar VT-X y luego reinicar para activarlo nuevamente. Después de que hagas esto el Docker debería reconocer que tienes la virtualización activa y por tanto no mostraría el error que coloqué en la descripción. Esta información la obtuve de buscar exhaustivamente una solución a mi problema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes confirmar si tu procesador soporta virtualización usando herramientas como [esta para Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005486/processors.html) o [esta para AMD](https://support.amd.com/en-us/search/utilities?k=virtualization). Ya con eso podrías ver si hace falta actualizar la BIOS o definitivamente no vale la pena.

Habría que probar también si puedes usar un guest de 32 bits, aunque Docker se supone que es x64 siempre...

Por último, veo que [boot2docker](https://github.com/boot2docker/windows-installer) fue deprecado y no veo requisitos específicos de VT-x/AMD-vt. Revisa la versión que tienes de Docker y prueba instalando [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/overview/#ready-to-get-started) en su lugar. Podría funcionar porque indican que es para sistemas viejos que no funcionan con Hyper-V, aunque en la documentación indican que

> Make sure your Windows system supports Hardware Virtualization
>   Technology and that virtualization is enabled.

Más ideas en un [post de SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24322380/is-it-possible-to-use-boot2docker-without-vt-x)...

Comment: Muy agradecido por tu respuesta y por tomarte el tiempo en colaborar a solventar mi duda. Debo agregar algunas cosas: 1) "oficialmente" no existe docker para 32 bits, sin embargo, existe un proyecto en Github que  te permite utilizar docker en este tipo de plataforma. 2) boot2docker no fue deprecado para windows 7 de hecho las trazas de error que te muestro son justamente utilizando docker toolbox y te puedo confirmar que utiliza un iso de boot2docker (repito para Windows 7 que es justamente el OS en el cual necesito que funcione).

Comment: Por otra parte: Comprobé en un principio si la maquina podía utilizar virtualización por hardware y lamentablemente no tiene esa capacidad y de allí el hecho de haber creado esta pregunta. Nuevamente gracias por el apoyo!

Comment: Lamento no poder ayudar más, @Huskie y muy importantes tus aclaraciones . Buena suerte!

Comment: muchas gracias, igual para tí!