# Por qué no existe oficialmente un Docker para Sistemas operativos de 32 bits (x86)?

Tags: linux, windows, docker

Estuve intentando instalar Docker 32 bits en una maquina como bien se puede observar en una pregunta en concreto que ayuda mejor a describir esta nueva pregunta: [Es posible utilizar docker en windows sin poseer VT-x/AMD-v?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/160329/es-posible-utilizar-docker-en-windows-sin-poseer-vt-x-amd-v)

> Poseo 3 fuertes motivos que me hacen cuestionar si existe alguna limitación técnica para lanzar una versión oficial de Docker para 32 bits, estos motivos son:
>
> 1) Mis innumerables intentos para intentar correr Docker en Windows
>   sin VT-x/AMD-v (como lo muestra mi anterior pregunta) que me
>   permitieron conocer la existencia de desarrollos no oficiales que si
>   pueden ser ejecutados en x32 bits
>
> 2) Docker puede ser ejecutado nativamente en Linux sin VT-x/AMD-v (yo
>   mismo lo comprobé utilizando docker en Debian 9 x64 bits)
>
> 3) En Windows puede ser ejecutado en x32 bits (para más información consulte
>   [docker windows 7](https://stefanscherer.github.io/yes-you-can-docker-on-windows-7/) y [Docker 32 bits](https://medium.com/@chrispatten/installing-and-running-docker-on-32-bit-windows-d18b95ee1fc3))

Uniendo estás 3 razones comentadas anteriormente me ha surgido la duda de por qué existen versiones no oficiales para 32 bits de Docker ([boot2docker](https://github.com/StefanScherer/boot2docker)) y por qué no existe una versión oficial del mismo para esta plataforma?

Podríamos tener una versión 32 bits de Docker para Linux sin que VT-x/AMD-v fuese necesario (como lo demuestra la versión para 64 bits) o bien podríamos tener una versión 32 bits para Windows donde si fuese necesario VT-x/AMD-v. También está demostrado por desarrollos no oficiales que sí se puede tener una versión de 32 bits.

Parece que el tipo de sistema operativo (si es Windows o Linux) no es limitante como tampoco lo es si tienes VT-x/AMD-v o no pero puede que aún así esté pasando por alto alguna otra cuestión técnica. Es por ello que en base a la pregunta que realizo se origina una duda en especifico y esta es: Existe alguna limitante/requerimiento técnico de peso importante que está impidiendo lanzar una versión oficial para 32 bits?

Agradezco de antemano su ayuda. Un saludo.

Comment: Me gustaría saber por qué puntuan negativamente mi pregunta? si dejan algún comentario podría saber si debo eliminarla o si se puede salvar modificandola... gracias

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro por favor podría verificar si mi pregunta tiene algo que merezca cierre? de ser así puede notificarme cuál es el motivo para intentar modificarla. No veo motivos para puntuación negativa o cierre pero me gustaría estar seguro igual porque requiero solucionar esta duda. Gracias y disculpe la molestia.

Comment: Yo no he votado negativo (pues contiene links interesantes para 32bits) pero supongo se debe a que puede ser interpretada como pregunta de opinión, algunas pistas de las "dificultades técnicas" se dan en el discurso de mercadeo de Vagrant https://www.vagrantup.com/intro/vs/docker.html (spoilers: vagrant usa maquinas virtuales completas, docker usa contenedores que son mas simples y rápidos de spawnear, pero dependen del sistema operativo subyacente siendo linux mas benévolo en ese sentido que windows )

Comment: Gracias por tu sugerencia @aloMalbarez y el Link sobre vagrant está excelente. Gracias por tu aporte. Si me temía que fuese por opinión pero es que cuando se habla de cuestiones técnicas dificilmente es una opinión y si existen versiones no oficiales de docker alguna razón (no opinión) importante debe haber por la cual no existe una versión oficial para 32 bits todavía

Comment: Por ejemplo una razón técnica de peso es la mencionada por @KacosPro en una pregunta que hice en meta y que me parece interesante rescatar de allá para colocarla aquí. Se puede leer en el siguiente link [mundo va a terminar el 19 de enero del 2038](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_del_año_2038). Pero es cierto me preocupa que sea interpretada como pregunta de opinión pero considero que la pregunta es importante aunque (de momento) no encuentro forma de plantearla mejor